# Swift - Performing Segue from UITableViewCells to different View Controller Destinations

Tags: uitableview, swift, segue, uistoryboardsegue

so I am having issues figuring out how to implement code for the following purpose:

Essentially my app allows a user on the opening screen to type different categories in a UItextfield, hit enter, and then have those categories appear in a UITableView (all on the same initial view controller). For example the user could enter "Friends from home", "College Friends", "NBA Players".

From there, I want the user to be able to drill down on one of the rows, and be taken by a segue to a UITableView controller where they can add names to those lists and ultimately be able to rank them for fun...

But my question currently is once the user has added the groups that he wants on the initial view controller, how does he/she drill down and segue to a SPECIFIC view controller based on the row he/she tapped?

(I want to post a picture of my storyboard but I don't have the necessary 10 reputation points yet!)

I tried code like this but have gotten no results. I will also note that I dragged a show segue from the uitableviewcell on the opening view controller to the UITableViewController (segue is named "EachGroup").

```
   override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if (segue.identifier == "EachGroup") {
        // pass data to next view
        let UIViewController:ViewController = segue.destinationViewController as ViewController
        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not a new question, many topics about.
You should specify a tag on each cell : `cell.tag = 0`

In your prepareForSegue, use :

```
if sender!.tag.littleEndian == 0
{
   let UIViewController:ViewController = segue.destinationViewController as YourSpecificViewcontroller
}
else if sender!.tag.littleEndian == 1
{
   let UIViewController:ViewController = segue.destinationViewController as YourOtherSpecificViewcontroller
}
```

Hope it helps,
Sidd.

Comment: Thanks that does. But two things: 1) im assuming i put the name of the tableviewcontroller destination after the "as". 2) does that mean i have to create a new tableviewcontroller for every possible destination? This seems inefficient if a user adds say 20 entries. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, 1) Yes, 2) yep, you should create a switch, more effiscient. Or, you should use `if(object_getClass(sender) === YourViewController.self)
{  //Code here
}`